# Modifying EditText Color in AlertDialog won't work

Tags: android, colors, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I'm a newbee in programming application for android. For my app I'm in need for 
password request after the application starts..... so far so good.

But in terms of calling my alertdialog the entered text i txtPIN can't be seen, thus it always have the same color as the background. I'm using API Lvl 17 as target API.

If anyone can give me a hint I would be glad.

```
        if (dbManager.getToggle()==true){

        final EditText txtPIN = new EditText(this);
        txtPIN.setTextColor(color.black);
        txtPIN.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);
        alert.setTitle("PIN Security");
        alert.setMessage("Please enter PIN");
        alert.setView(txtPIN);
        alert.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        alert.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                //comparison of PINs
                if (txtPIN.getText().toString().equals(dbManager.getPIN()){
                    Toast toast =  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.allowed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 150);
                    toast.show();

                } else {
                    Toast toast =  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.denied) + "\n" + txtPIN.getText().toString() + "\n" + dbManager.getPIN(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 150);
                    toast.show();

                    finish();
                    System.exit(0);
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: I think that the problem is that the `EditText` is created with the apps `context` and not that of the `AlertDialog`. The `EditText` thus can not possibly know about the theme as it can not guess where it is going to be placed. Try to first create an `AlertDialog` by calling `AlertDialog dialog = alert.create()` and then create your edit text with `final EditText txtPIN = new EditText(dialog.getContext());`.

Answer (score 0):

Create your `EditText` using xml like such:

```
<EditText xmlns:andoird="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/edit_text"
     android:inputType="number"
     android:textColor="#000000"
     android:OTHER_ATTRIBUTES_HERE/>
```

And then create your `AlertDialog` like such:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);
 LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
 View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_text_xml_file, null));
    alert.setTitle("PIN Security");
    alert.setMessage("Please enter PIN");
    alert.setView(v);
    alert.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    EditText txtPIN = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

    alert.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            //comparison of PINs
            if (txtPIN.getText().toString().equals(dbManager.getPIN()){
                Toast toast =  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.allowed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 150);
                toast.show();

            } else {
                Toast toast =  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.denied) + "\n" + txtPIN.getText().toString() + "\n" + dbManager.getPIN(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 150);
                toast.show();

                finish();
                System.exit(0);
            }

        }
```